# Como parar de receber digitos do teclado?

Tags: c, scanf

Isto é um jogo da memória e enquanto os números estão a ser exibidos quero que o utilizador não possa digitar.

```
**for (i=0;i<2;i++) //Exibe os números que estão no vetor numeros[]
                            {
                                printf ("%d\t", numeros[i]); //Mostra no ecrã
                            }
                            Sleep (1000); //Aguarda 1 segundo
                        }
                        while (j>0); //Esta sequência acontece até que o j seja maior do que 0

                        system ("cls"); // Limpa o ecrã
                        printf ("Que números foram exibidos? \n\n"); //Mostra no ecrã


                        for (i=0;i<2;i++)
                        {
                            printf ("\t%d° número: ", i+1); //Pede todos os números para o utilizador
                            scanf ("%d", &respostas[i]); //Recebe os números do utilizadorfor (i=0;i<2;i++) //Exibe os números que estão no vetor numeros[]
                            {
                                printf ("%d\t", numeros[i]); //Mostra no ecrã
                            }
                            Sleep (1000); //Aguarda 1 segundo
                        }
                        while (j>0); //Esta sequência acontece até que o j seja maior do que 0

                        system ("cls"); // Limpa o ecrã
                        printf ("Que números foram exibidos? \n\n"); //Mostra no ecrã


                        for (i=0;i<2;i++)
                        {
                            printf ("\t%d° número: ", i+1); //Pede todos os números para o utilizador
                            scanf ("%d", &respostas[i]); //Recebe os números do utilizador**
```

Comment: Pra ser sincero sua pergunta está bem confusa.. não tem um print do console para exemplificar o que quer? De qualquer maneira, acredito que talvez possa resolver você utilizar uma variável do tipo booleano para determinar se pode ou não pedir números ao usuário.. é uma forma.

Comment: O meu programa gera números e esses números vão aparecer durante x tempo para o utilizador memorizar. De seguida o utilizador precisa de dizer quais os números que foram mostrados. Agora, o problema está em que o utilizador pode escrever as respostas enquanto os números estão a ser mostrados.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente esta meio confuso, seria legal se voce colocasse as regras do jogo. Sugiro que voce tente fazer algo nesse sentido:

```
while(acertos != x)
//enquanto o usuario nao acertar todos os numeros o programa continua
{
   for (i=0;i<2;i++) //Exibe os números que estão no vetor numeros[]
   {
        printf ("%d\t", numeros[i]); //Mostra no ecrã
        Sleep (1000); //Aguarda 1 segundo
        system("cls");
   }

printf ("Que números foram exibidos? \n\n"); //Mostra no ecrã


for (i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    printf ("\t%d° número: ", i+1); //Pede todos os números para o utilizador
    scanf ("%d", &respostas[i]); //Recebe os números do utilizadorfor (i=0;i<2;i++) //Exibe os números que estão no vetor numeros[]
}
// voce pode colocar um if else, como não sei a regra do jogo não vou colocar,
//mas se for oq eu estou pensando, se o usuario acertar os numeros voce acrescenta no
//contador acertos++, caso errar voce mostra o os numeros novamente

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o comando `stty -echo` e `stty echo` numa chamada do `system()`, onde `stty -echo` desativa a aparição da entrada do teclado, e   `stty echo` e ativa de volta, como dito [neste post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40973391/how-to-prevent-shell-from-getting-input-keyboard-while-running-a-python-script).

No seu caso basta rodar o comando antes do sleep, o código ficaria assim:

```
**for (i=0;i<2;i++) //Exibe os números que estão no vetor numeros[]
                            {
                                printf ("%d\t", numeros[i]); //Mostra no ecrã
                            }
                            system("stty -echo");
                            Sleep (1000); //Aguarda 1 segundo
                            system("stty echo");
                        }
                        while (j>0); //Esta sequência acontece até que o j seja maior do que 0

                        system ("cls"); // Limpa o ecrã
                        printf ("Que números foram exibidos? \n\n"); //Mostra no ecrã


                        for (i=0;i<2;i++)
                        {
                            printf ("\t%d° número: ", i+1); //Pede todos os números para o utilizador
                            scanf ("%d", &respostas[i]); //Recebe os números do utilizadorfor (i=0;i<2;i++) //Exibe os números que estão no vetor numeros[]
                            {
                                printf ("%d\t", numeros[i]); //Mostra no ecrã
                            }
                            system("stty -echo");
                            Sleep (1000); //Aguarda 1 segundo
                            system("stty echo");
                        }
                        while (j>0); //Esta sequência acontece até que o j seja maior do que 0

                        system ("cls"); // Limpa o ecrã
                        printf ("Que números foram exibidos? \n\n"); //Mostra no ecrã


                        for (i=0;i<2;i++)
                        {
                            printf ("\t%d° número: ", i+1); //Pede todos os números para o utilizador
                            scanf ("%d", &respostas[i]); //Recebe os números do utilizador**
```

Essa solução funciona para o terminal Bash ( padrão do ubuntu ), caso esteja num ambiente windows, talvez precise adaptar o comando.